# Throwing beautifulSoup encoding error intermittently

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse html pages, sometimes it throws encoding error like "encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x9D 0x3C 0x2F 0x74" 
I tried to catch this error with try except block to know exactly what lines causes the error because I have many lines with BeautifulSoup but it didn't work because it looks like BeautifulSoup only reports the error to stderr and ignore these characters and continue working

```
r  = requests.get("someurl")
try:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

is there a way to know what line exactly throws the error and what are the character/s that causes the encoding error?

Comment: try `import logging` and then in `except` `logging.exception(str(e))`

Comment: it doesn't go to exception block so there is no e

Comment: show all traceback

Comment: You could try to save `r.content` to a byte string (or write it to a file) and search it for the character `'\x9d'`. But inspecting the characters around that position, you should be able to find where in the text the problem occurs.

Comment: I want to catch the error BeautifulSoup report, problem is I think BeautifulSoup  only reports the error to stderr so it actually doesn't assert the error